# VBA Can 'with' statement cover several ranges or objects?

Tags: excel, vba

Just wanted to know if the following code could be simplified without adding an array or a loop.

Variables Cell1, Cell2 & Cell3 are highly independent. That means they won't be the same every time, as they will come from several previous calculations.

```
    With Rng
        With .Columns(Cell1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Columns(Cell2).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With .Columns(Cell3).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
```

Is there a way to write something like:

```
    With Rng
        With .Columns(Cell1).Interior, .Columns(Cell2).Interior, .Columns(Cell3).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
```

Thanks,

Comment: Probably can be simplified to just three lines:  `Rng.Columns(Cell1).Interior.Color = vbYellow` and then two more for `Cell2` and `Cell3`. Or maybe even one line if using `Union` as demonstrated in the posted answer. The `.PatternColorIndex`, `.TintAndShade`, and `.PatternTintAndShade` are superfluous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Union.

```vb
    With Rng
        With Union(.Columns(Cell1), .Columns(Cell2), .Columns(Cell3)).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
```

Comment: Could get rid of the `.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic`, `.TintAndShade = 0`, and `.PatternTintAndShade = 0` too. They're superfluous. Also `vbYellow` is a bit more meaningful than `65535`.

Comment: @BigBen Good idea. That would also eliminate the need for both `With` statements.